# DataContractSerialize error

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010

Here a little test code illustrating the problem:

### Compiling configurations:

Common Language Runtime Support: /clr

C++ Language

### Error message:

Error   4   error C2065: 'DataContractSerializer' : undeclared identifier   C:...\SerializationTest.cpp    21  1   SerializationTest

### The code:

```
// SerializationTest.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System;

using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace System::Runtime::Serialization;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");

    Dictionary<System::String^, System::Double>^ teste = gcnew Dictionary<System::String^, System::Double>();
    teste->Add("Teste1",2);
    teste->Add("Teste2",4);    

    DataContractSerializer^ serializer = gcnew DataContractSerializer(teste->GetType());
    StringWriter^ writer = gcnew StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter^ stm = gcnew XmlTextWriter(writer);
    serializer->WriteObject(stm, teste);

    Console::WriteLine(writer->ToString());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds simply like you're missing a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll (which is required *in addition to* the `using` directive):

```
#using <System.Runtime.Serialization.dll>
```